# call multiple methods of a function at one time

Tags: javascript, function, methods, prototype

If I have pseudo code like :

```
  function user(a,b)
  {
    if(! (this instanceof user) ) return new user(a,b);
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.showName = function() {
      alert(this.a + " " + this.b);
    };

    this.changeName = function(a,b) {
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
    };
  }
```

I can call it like :

```
user("John", "Smith").showName() // output : John Smith
```

I want something like :

```
user("John", "Smith").changeName("Adam", "Smith").showName();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Return the object in every method. This is called "chaining".

```
  function user(a,b)
  {
    if(! (this instanceof user) ) return new user(a,b);
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.showName = function() {
      alert(this.a + " " + this.b);

      return this; // <--- returning this
    };

    this.changeName = function(a,b) {
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;

      return this; // <--- returning this
    };
}
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/oromed/

Comment: For future reference, this pattern is called "chaining".

Comment: Please learn what [`scope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/) is